# Using ofstream << operator

Tags: c++, file, c++11, file-writing

I am trying to write in a large file. My initial implementation was simply using `std::cout` and then redirecting the output to another file.

I made another implementation where I use `std::ofstream` where I write directly to a file and when I compared the two versions, when looking at them the files seemed exactly the same.

Yet when I tried using something like `diff` or `cmp` the files turned out to be completely different. Could the fact that I used the `<<` operator with `std::ofstream` instead of the `std::ofstream::write` function be the reason of this? I am thinking that the text was encoded in a different kind of way.

I can't put the whole code out here because it's too long but I hope the sample will suffice. I am asking a conceptual question anyways.

```
void write_file(){
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("MyFile.txt");
    myfile<<"write data\n";
    ...
}

int main(){

    write_file();
    return 0;
}
```

Running it,

```
./mycompiledprogram
```

Other method,

```
int main(){
    std::cout<<"write data"<<std::endl;
}
```

Running it,

```
./mycompiledprogram > MyFile.txt
```

Using **diff** I got that every line differed from the other although it appeared to be the same.
Comparing using **cmp** I got something like this

```
cmp -b file1.txt file2.txt
file1.txt file2.txt differ: byte 8, line 1 is  15 ^M  12 ^J
```

Comment: Do you have some sample code?

Comment: Sure formatted output (<<) and unformatted output (write) are different. Also, the open-mode (std::ios_base::binary) may effect the result.

Comment: Thank you Dieter, I am really surprised with this stackoverflow community. They downvote you because they don't know the answer and blame it on the person for not explaining the problem well.

Comment: @stryker: You don't give us an example of the actual code. No example of the differences between the files. It isn't a good question. The only answers possible are psychic guesses.

Comment: ***They downvote you because they don't know the answer*** I would say in this case they downvoted you because you did not post your minimal code showing your problem.

Comment: Still not enough information **Yet when I tried using something like diff or cmp the files turned out to be completely different.** What are the differences?

Comment: I made all the requested changes I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Your output shows the differences are linefeeds and carriage returns.

Answer (score 1):

In the ofstream method you write the end-of-line with a '\n'

In the cout method you write the end-of-line with a std::endl

I guess on your platform the std::endl is not equivalent to '\n' and that's why you have every line different.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function `bool CompareFiles(ifstream& f1, ifstream&f2)` which compares two files line-by-line. I don't know how you've chosen to structure your file, but you could say: `f1.getline(buff1, '\n')` and `f2.getline(buff2, '\n')`. Now all you have to do is compare the two strings.